# Unable to find a version of 'RazorEngine' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.2'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-3

I try to update Nuget to my ASP.NET MVC5 project and the Razor cannot be resolved.

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'jQuery (≥ 1.9.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'WebGrease (≥ 1.5.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Antlr (≥ 3.4.1.9004)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 5.0.4)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 5.2.2 && < 5.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.2.2 && < 5.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 5.2.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http (≥ 2.2.22)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl (≥ 1.1.9)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build (≥ 1.0.14)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.OData (≥ 5.6.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (= 5.6.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Edm (= 5.6.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (= 2.0.30506.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (≥ 3.0.0)'.

Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2.0.30506.0' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.2' failed.
Unable to find a version of 'RazorEngine' that is compatible
with 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.2'.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have two versions of Razor installed, have you tried uninstalling one of them?

Comment: I am trying to cleanup razor reference and I can't find Razor 3.0.0.0. Do I need to install something? I have Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Comment: Probably just the framework. Razor is a dependency of Mvc: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`